# C# console app for SVN hook not getting command line arguments

Tags: c#, svn, visualsvn-server, pre-commit-hook

I've written a C# console application to use as an SVN pre-commit hook. I'm using [this](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) to parse the launch parameters. It's running on VisualSVN, and according to the VisualSVN [documentation](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/pre-commit/):

> **Input parameter(s)**
>
> The command-line arguments passed to the hook program, in order, are:
>
> - Repository path
> - Commit transaction name

I don't seem to be picking up the arguments passed into the application when run via the hook. If I run the application from the console, passing in the arguments manually, it works correctly, but when called by the SVN, the `args` array is empty, and the command line parser doesn't pick up anything.

I've added this by specifying an absolute path to the exe in the pre-commit hook property in VisualSVN (`C:\Scripts\pre-commit.exe`). Is this correct/do I need to do anything special to get the arguments to pass to the application?

Comment: Looks like you've identified the main problems here; "the args array is empty". Without seeing any code it's hard to say where the issue is but from your description I'd hazard a guess it's around where you're calling your pre-commit app. What code is being used to call it?

Comment: Hmm, do you put the executable to e.g. `C:\Repositories\MyRepo\hooks`? Or do you call it via a batch file as a wrapper by some reason?

Comment: I'm calling it with `C:\Scripts\pre-commit.exe` in the Visual SVN pre-commit hook dialog. I did also try it with a batch file wrapper, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the pre-commit.exe file has to be placed inside the repo hooks directory. Once I moved it there, it got hit with the correct parameters. I *think* the Visual SVN pre-commit hook dialog actually creates a batch file, and it was losing the arguments when it called the executable.

I could probably also have tweaked the behaviour of that wrapper to make it work, but dropping the executable in there did the trick.